# OnClickListener issue in android

Tags: android, onclicklistener

```
package com.example.firstproject;


import android.app.Activity;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int counter;

TextView display;
Button add,sub;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       counter=0;
       add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
       sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bSub);
       display =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

      add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener......);

     }
}
```

problem is: OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a variable

i have checked other posts and fix it for imports but still not getting the reason

Comment: Try going to Project -> Clean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Your code here.
    }
});
```

Comment: thanx...it worked like magic, but what is reason behind this, i have just started with android so don't know much.

Comment: There are different `OnClickListeners` and you need to define which one you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //IMPLEMENTATION
    }
});
```